# Why does chown report "Operation not permitted" on OS X?

Tags: macos, file-permissions

I am trying to do the following on my Mac (10.6.7):

```
sudo chown myusername:wheel ./entries
```

but Unix/Mac is returning "Operation not permitted". When I `ls -lash` the culprit file, it looks as follows:

```
8 -rwxrwxrwx   1 myusername  staff   394B Apr 26 23:26 entries
```

I've tried `sudo` and `sudo su`; nothing works. Any ideas what's up?

I'm trying to `chmod` files I've copied from my old Ubuntu box. Most of the files have successfully `chmod`'ed recursively; just this one is stuck and I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chgrp wheel ./entries`?

Comment: Do a file system check. Open Disk Utility, select your volume, and click *Verify Disk*, then, if necessary, *Repair Disk*.

Comment: Make sure the file is not locked in Finder (no lock badge on the icon). To change it, open the *Get Info* dialog and uncheck *Locked*.

Comment: If it is an "external" volume (i.e. not the system volume), you may have to remove the "Ignore ownership on this volume" option. (See at the bottom of the Get Info window for the volume itself).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Yes, Mac has many enhancements to Unix in the area of files.  Ignoring the whole [*resource fork*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork) thing which is not used much anymore, there are:

- the **standard Unix permissions** `ugo` `rwx` and so on.  Normal Unix tools apply.
- **ACL**'s, viewable with `ls -le` and changeable with `chmod [ -a | +a | =a ]`.
- **file flags** viewable with `ls -lO` (Capital oh, not zero) and changeable with `chflags`.
- **extended attributes**, viewable with `ls -l@` (attribute keys only) and viewable and changeable with `xattr`.  (Use `xattr -h` for help if `man xattr` does not give you anything.)
- Starting with OS X 10.11 "El Capitan", **[System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)** (SIP) further protects some files from changes from ordinary processes, even when using `sudo` to run as `root`. Files protected by SIP will be listed by `ls -lO` as having the `restricted` flag and/or be listed by `ls -l@` as having the `com.apple.rootless` attribute.

You can be denied operations on a file because of Unix permissions, ACLs, file flags, or SIP.  To fully unlock a file:

```
sudo chmod -N file        # Remove ACLs from file
sudo chmod ugo+rw file    # Give everyone read-write permission to file
sudo chflags nouchg file  # Clear the user immutable flag from file
sudo chflags norestricted file  # Remove the SIP protection from file
sudo xattr -d com.apple.rootless file # Remove SIP protection from file
```

If System Integrity Protection (SIP) is enabled, `sudo chflags norestricted` and `sudo xattr -d com.apple.rootless` will also return an "Operation not permitted" error. To clear the flag and/or attribute you need to boot into [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and either run the commands from Terminal (you may have to first use Disk Utility to unlock and mount your boot drive, then remember your files will be under `/Volumes/Macintosh HD` or whatever your boot drive is named) or [disable SIP altogether](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html) and then reboot and the commands should then work. Be aware, however, that future OS updates will likely restore the `restricted` flag and `com.apple.rootless` attribute to any files you removed it from.

***Disabling SIP is not recommended*** as it removes lots of protection against malware and accidental damage, plus it is not necessary when you can simply remove the protection on a per-file basis. If you do disable SIP, re-enable it when you are done making changes.

Note that if `ls -lO` shows the `schg` flag is set, you have to get into single-user mode to unset it.  I'm not going to get into that here as there are bigger questions about why the file has that flag set and why you are trying to mess with it and what the consequences will be.

Comment: Adding to this, other flags might prevent you to change your files. In my script I put `sudo chflags -R nouchg,noschg,nouappnd,nosappnd,noopaque,dump .`

Comment: Note: if something has the "unchangeable" flag, the Locked checkbox in Get Info will be checked and grayed out. "sudo chflags nouchg" fixes it.

Comment: I couldn't do the `-N` and `ugo+rw` both at once (I got `Failed to clear ACL on file ugo+rw: No such file or directory`) but running them individually worked fine. If recursive is desired the `-R` must be the first arg.

Comment: Note that System Integrity Protection (rootless) can also cause this on El Capitan and later. To resolve that, boot into Recovery Mode (`Cmd-R`), open Terminal and run `csrutil disable`, then restart (to reenable, use `csrutil enable`).

Comment: Thank you ... I had no idea about file flags. Now I understand why it said `override rwxrwxrwx  huttarl/staff uchg for green.html?`

Comment: Do you also need to change permissions on the directory that owns the file?

Comment: `man xattr` shows me a manpage with Apple-specific notes - not sure when this was added since the manpage itself is dated from Nov 29, 2010 (before this post was made).

Comment: I was scratching my head why my rsync script was was squawking about `Operation not permitted` for matching ownership until I ran across your post. This particular issue was fixed by `sudo chflags -R nouchg .` in the root of the backup up tree. Thanks. **Very helpful!**

Comment: When booted into the recovery partition, `xattr` is not in the path.  Running it via `/Volumes/xxx/usr/bin/xattr` results in a "bad interpreter" error on Python.  Trying to run `xattr` via `/Volumes/xxx/usr/bin/python /Volumes/xxx/usr/bin/xattr` results in an error on a file in the Python framework.

Comment: In my case I was trying to delete `/Application/iTunes.app`.  Even booting into the recovery partition, turning off SIP, rebooting, and then trying to run `xattr` to remove rootless resulted in an error: 

`xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Applications/iTunes.app'`

I gave up and deleted the file while booted into the recovery partition.

Comment: @jetset Not sure what OS version you were on but in recent OS versions, even though it looks like your hard drive is on one volume, Apple's apps are actually located on a different volume and can't be deleted. I'm not exactly sure how it works under the hood but /Applications/iTunes.app may not actually exist as far as Terminal is concerned when you're booted from the disk that looks like it containes it.

Comment: @John Smith the accepted answer explained the issue (System Integrity Protection [SIP]) was not allowing modification to the file. Temporarily disabling SIP allowed it to be modified.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. It turns out that the offending files were marked as "Locked" by the OS. I found this solution and it solved the problems in seconds:

http://explanatorygap.net/2005/07/10/unlocking-files-recursively-from-the-command-line/

> It seems like the `rm` command has changed in Tiger such that if you use `rm -Rf` with elevated privileges, it will automatically unlock the files.

In OS X before Tiger: `find /Volumes/Transit -flags +uchg -print0 | xargs -0 chflags nouchg`

In OS X after Tiger: `sudo rm -Rf foldername/`

Also, even after OS X 10.4, there may be file metadata flags such as `uchg` and `uappnd`, which prevent any modification of the file permissions or ownership.  `chflags` can remove
the flags.
Some of the file attributes/metadata and how they are handled by different copy tools are [here](http://blog.plasticsfuture.org/2006/03/05/the-state-of-backup-and-cloning-tools-under-mac-os-x/).

Comment: `sudo rm -Rf foldername/` is working perfectly on OSX Mountain Lion

Comment: @Aryo: `rm` deletes the directory. Is there a way to just unlock everything without deleting it? When I look `uchg` is not set, and I can turn it on and off again as expected (with `chflags [no]uchg`), but that has no effect on the lock icon in the Finder, or on my ability to `chown`.

Comment: You are telling people to PERMANENTLY DELETE directories?! not change permissions. This answer should be removed.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as the last @John. Why is there an answer here talking about deleting directories? That's not what the question was about. Also, the link is broken, that's why you're supposed to give answers here, not link to them.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with the Crashplan.app.

All the solutions listed here would not help me, but this one did the trick:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1546163

You have to change the system and user immutable flags:

Do this to see which flags are active on your file/folder:

```
ls -lhdO MyFile
```

The response might look like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 root admin schg,uchg 102B Apr 8 2013 MyFile
```

**schg**,**uchg** are those immutable flags. One for the system and one for the user.
To remove them, do the following:

```
chflags noschg CrashPlan.app # this removes system immutable flag
chflags nouchg CrashPlan.app # this removes the user immutable flags
```

Then, for me at least, the file is unlocked and you can delete it!

Comment: Awesome, had to `chflags` using `sudo` though, but it makes sense

Comment: Had the same issue with CrashPlan.app (I had `drwxrwxr-x@ 3 _BGMXPCHelper  admin  schg   96B  9 Jan  2018 CrashPlan.app`), and this one was the only solution that allowed me to delete it, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

In OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), this can also be caused by the new **Rootless** feature. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) for an explanation.

In short, for certain important directories, there is no way to modify them — whether you use `sudo`, `chown` or `chmod`. This affects the `/usr` directory, (although you are allowed to modify `/usr/local`).

To modify a Rootless-protected directory, you need to [disable Rootless](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11). And, of course, re-enable it after making your modifications, because it is an important security enhancement.

Comment: Wow. That drove me nuts. Somehow I needed to copy something to /usr/lib which was otherwise not found in /usr/local/lib (don't ask me why). And that did the trick.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to disable Rootless altogether, you can just boot into Recovery mode (which you'd have to do anyway to disable Rootless) and make the changes you want from the Terminal there.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of struggling, here's what I had to do to get the problem fixed:

- Moved the file to `~/Desktop`
- `sudo chown myusername:staff ./entries`
- Moving the file back to it's original location didn't work (Operation not permitted, again), so...
- `sudo rm ./entries`
- `sudo mv ~/Desktop/entries ./entries`

Comment: You really should take the highest voted answer as 'the answer'. It is complete and accurate.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, about my home folder. At the end i just used finder like this:

Go -> Computer -> your disk -> Users -> your user name -> right click -> Get Info

I found that it was locked, probably i did it in the past and forgot. Unchecked the locked checkbox, problem fixed.

I can recommend using 'Get Info' from finder in order to tackle this kind of problems.

(OS X 10.8.3)

Comment: This helped me to unlock `.iso` from glitchy Virtual Box.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure both the file and its parent folder are unlocked

I was facing a similar problem when trying to delete a Mac Mail email signature file. I could not delete it until I had unlocked the file as well as its parent folder.