# Permission denied when trying to cd /usr/local/bin from terminal

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

From the terminal, I tried to go to usr\local\bin under my user name login id, but I got the Permission denied. Same as ls command.  Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
mac1:/ user1$ ls -la /usr/local

total 0

drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel  170 Feb 15 17:53 .

drwxr-xr-x@ 12 root  wheel  408 Jan 16 14:30 ..

drwx------  19 504   wheel  646 Feb 15 18:39 bin

drwxrwxr-x   4 root  admin  136 Dec 16 08:47 lib

drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  204 Feb 15 17:53 share
```

Comment: Can you please show us the output of `ls -la /usr/local`?

Comment: @slhck: Please the edit.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In versions of OS X or macOS previous to High Sierra (10.13), you could just type:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

This does not apply to macOS 10.13 or above, as System Integrity Protection will ensure the ownership of `/usr/local` cannot be changed.

Or if you want it specific to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

Also, your permission modes are off—ideally `/usr/local/bin` should be accessible by others too:

```
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I don't generally recommend using numeric modes (like 755) with recursive changes -- it's likely to add execute access to plain files that shouldn't be executable (although in the case of a bin directory it's probably not a problem). Instead use something like `sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX /usr/local/bin` -- the "X" mode sets execute access only if it looks appropriate.

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you. Like you said, I only wrote this because we were talking about a `bin` directory.

Comment: Not really a good idea. This might change the owner of binaries which could stall process and give you a hard time. Better selectively "own" single binaries that you need.

Comment: Talking about how this happens, it looks like macport for instance creates this status. At least it created it on my mac.
`drwx------  29 macports  wheel   986B  8 Aug 14:01 bin`

Comment: I am getting the below error when doing so (I have tried with and without sudo):
`chown: changing ownership of '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose': Operation not permitted
`

Comment: @FahadUddin Please create a new question for this issue, but first check https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x/518545 and

Answer (score 0):

I simply placed cd (change directory) in front of /usr/local/bin
and it `joshuafranklin@Joshuas-MBP bin %`
First time using mac to run python