# Chrome crashpad crashes on xattr

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, file-attributes

I have a macos High Sierra 10.13.3. When running Chrome in headless mode to execute automated tests, I get this error:

```
[0207/114344.742771:ERROR:xattr.cc(64)] setxattr org.chromium.crashpad.database.initialized on file /var/folders/8c/s_296_fd25sfywfxclkjcz_w0000gp/T/: Operation not permitted (1)
[karma2] [0207/114344.743721:INFO:crashpad_client_mac.cc(292)] restarting handler in 0.980s
```

I have tried to clear the extended attributes on that file with `xattr -c /var/folders/8c/s_296_fd25sfywfxclkjcz_w0000gp/T/` but I'm also getting an Operation Not Permitted, even with `sudo`.

I can list the attributes:

```
$ xattr /var/folders/8c/s_296_fd25sfywfxclkjcz_w0000gp/T
com.apple.rootless
```

So how can I fix the permissions on this file? It use to work until recently.

Comment: Does [this question and (very) clear answer](https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x) provide a solution?

Comment: I tried the 4 commands suggested in that post, but I'm still getting the issue. I can't `sudo chown` , I get a `Operation Not Permitted`

Comment: @agtoever Intrigued to know why you think a 6 year old solution to an unrelated problem (aside from part of the error message) is likely to work here..

Answer (score 13):

There is a simple workaround. Just provide a different directory for "crash dumps" when starting Chrome, like this:

```
path_to_chrome --headless --crash-dumps-dir=/tmp
```