# How to replace a file in “/usr/bin” in MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos

I need to edit a script in `/usr/bin`, but the system won't me let do it because the SIP. How can I do it? It's a PHP script needed for my development environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does chown report "Operation not permitted" on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x)

Comment: First, [the answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1363080/167207) is utterly correct. You should not disable SIP unless you have a very strong reason to do so. That said, you state “It's a PHP script needed for my development environment.” This makes no sense. I develop in PHP on macOS—web and system script level—and utterly nothing I have ever encountered required I install anything in a deep system path on macOS like this. You might be asking a different question than what you intend; perhaps you should actually explain why you need to install a PHP script in `/usr/bin/` to begin with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the best answer is: *don't*. Changing things in the protected directories may break parts of the OS that use them. Local customizations belong in `/usr/local` rather than the main hierarchy, and `/usr/local/bin` is already in the default `PATH` (and before `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, so commands there will be used in preference to the builtins). Just put the modified script there, and it should work for most purposes.

If you do need to make mods in `/usr/bin`, you can turn off filesystem protection by restarting in recovery mode, and running the command:

```
csrutil enable --without fs
```

...then restart normally, do the changes, then restart in recovery again, run `csrutil enable`, and restart again. See [Rich Trouton's blog](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/) for *way* more information.