# Home folder not accessible after migrating user profile from OS X 10.9 to macOS 10.14

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, osx-mavericks, macos-mojave

I am trying to migrate a user from an old mid 2010 iMac with OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) to a new iMac Pro with macOS 10.14 (Mojave).

Using the Migration Assistant with a time machine backup of the old machine seems to work -- all things seem to be back in place (Mail has the old accounts, all files are there, etc.).

Unfortunately, there is one issue with the home folder: I cannot open it in Finder -- it is 'transparent/grayed out' and it is not possible to open it via double-click. However, I can directly browse to its contents via the "Go To Folder"-command (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>). Also in the terminal, for some operations on the folder i get the error message "Operation not permitted".

I did verify that the folder is not locked (as this seems to be the default issue with the transparent/grayed symbol). Also the file permissions I can see via 'right click-->Get Info' are correct (I and can read+write, the group can read, everybody can read).

The terminal command `ls -l@ "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users"` returns: `drwxr-xr-x@` next to my home folder, which is different from the default(?) permissions `drwxr-xr-x+`. I followed the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/279235/why-does-chown-report-operation-not-permitted-on-os-x) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203538) to reset permissions and remove all flags and extended attributes (there were 5 or 6 in total. Unfortunately, I did not write them down. Two of them had sth. like 'oldest time machine snapshot' and 'newest time machine snapshot' in their name).

That is (following the superuser post linked above), i did:

```
sudo chmod -N "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me"       # Remove ACLs from file
sudo chmod ugo+rw "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me"   # Give everyone read-write permission to file
sudo chflags nouchg "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me" # Clear the user immutable flag from file
sudo chflags norestricted "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me" # Remove the SIP protection from file
```

followed by using the corresponding commands `sudo xattr -d com.apple.XXXYYYZZZ "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/me"` to remove all extended attributes, and finally followed by resetting the user permissions of the folder (as detailed here) via:

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

This resulted in the permissions of my home folder becoming `drwxr-xr-x` (no "+"!) and still the home folder is not accessible.

What could be other reasons for this behavior & how can I fix them? Alternatively: What would be my best alternative route to migrate the old user to the new system?

Comment: I know this is a bit late to the party but....did you ever find a proper solution that wasn't a terminal hack?

Comment: @I_Don't_Code Other than what's available in the Finder's Get Info window, there likely isn't going to be a permissions repair that isn't a terminal hack at the very least (more likely it will require booting into Recovery and using terminal from there) since Apple very intelligently and helpfully took away the GUI for users to do it, and, after looking for two days, I'm starting to think that in Mojave, there isn't one at all.  If there is, I haven't found it yet.