# Can't clear ACL on macOS file - Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

I have a MacBook Pro with an external USB hard drive. A program I wrote is having trouble reading the files in `Backups.backupdb` so I look at the permissions:

```
> pwd
/Volumes/G-DRIVE
> ls -led Backups.backupdb 
drwxr-xr-x+ 7 rob  staff  238 Feb 10  2012 Backups.backupdb
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

This is an older drive. I no longer use it for Time Machine backups, so I don't care if I clear out permissions that used to protect this folder

But I can't clear them:

```
> sudo chmod -N Backups.backupdb
> chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Backups.backupdb: Operation not permitted
```

Attempts to find some hidden attribute that might be preventing the chmod:

```
> ls -ldO Backups.backupdb 
> drwxr-xr-x+ 7 rob  staff  - 238 Feb 10  2012 Backups.backupdb
> xattr Backups.backupdb 
[nothing]
```

Why is the operation not permitted?

I just used Disk Utility to look at the drive. It didn't find any problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question.

I don't know if this is new to macOS 11 Big Sur. I had to go to System Preferences → Security & Privacy → the Privacy tab. Then select "Full Disk Access" in the list on the left, and enable the checkbox for Terminal. It restarted Terminal and then I was able to run the usual commands to `chmod`, as well as view the directory contents.

Comment: Ahh, you didn't mention you were running Big Sur. Indeed, "Full Disk Access" is not an option on Catalina. Glad the mystery is resolved.

Comment: "Full Disk Access" actually is an option in Catalina.

Comment: Works on Monterey as well. I suggest suggesting this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Being unable to do operations even with `sudo` is usually caused by System Integrity Protection. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/518545/809729) describes a similar issue, and also describes how to disable SIP (and re-enable it when you're done).

Comment: I don't think it's SIP. If it were, I should see that `rootless` attr when I run `xattr`, but there's nothing there.

Comment: Perhaps. Have you investigated `chflags` ? Here's an answer that describes another similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7545798/6423998

Comment: That `ls -ldO` command that I show in my question shows there are no flags on the directory.